# How to filter Magento api catalog_product.list in iOS?

Tags: ios, magento, soap

I am trying to use Magento's api using SOAP request in iOS.

I am using [SOAPEngine](https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine) to make requests and retrieve the data.

I am able to login using the following code

```
self.soap = [[SOAPEngine alloc] init];
self.soap.userAgent = @"SOAPEngine";
self.soap.delegate = self; // use SOAPEngineDelegate

// each single value
[self.soap setValue:@"adminUserName" forKey:@"username"];
[self.soap setValue:@"adminPassword" forKey:@"apiKey"];
// service url without ?WSDL, and you can search the soapAction in the WSDL
[self.soap requestURL:@"http://192.168.1.50/projects/usapool/api/"
      soapAction:@"http://192.168.1.50/projects/usapool/api/login"];
```

but when I try to call the `catalog_product.list` as mentioned on [catalog_product.list API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html) with `filters` as follows

```
NSMutableDictionary *filterDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[filterDictionary setValue:@"28" forKey:@"product_id"];

// each single value
[self.soap setValue:sessionId forKey:@"sessionId"];
[self.soap setValue:@"catalog_product.list" forKey:@"resourcePath"];
[self.soap setValue:filterDictionary forKey:@"filters"];

// service url without ?WSDL, and you can search the soapAction in the WSDL
[self.soap requestURL:@"http://192.168.1.50/projects/usapool/api/"
               soapAction:@"http://192.168.1.50/projects/usapool/api/call"];
```

I get the array of all the products and filter is not applied.

Does anybody know how to apply the filters in this case?

Comment: Are you sure `filters` key takes a dictionary as the argument? Seems like it takes an array after looking at the API reference. `[self.soap setValue:filterDictionary forKey:@"filters"];`

Comment: Yes is has to be passed as a `NSDictionary`